# What do the numbers [master +2 ~0 -0 !] beside the branch name mean?

Tags: git, repository, posh-git

I have just started learning git. I don't understand what these numbers beside `master` mean.

[image: Numbers beside branch name]

Comment: Without explicitly knowing I would hazard a guess at it showing the current status. My guess would be that you're 2 commits ahead of origin, no modified files, and no commits behind origin (you can be both ahead and behind origin at the same time). Try a `git status` to see if the numbers line up.

Comment: That seems to be posh-git. You might find the answer in [the documentation](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#git-status-summary-information).

Comment: @JJJ Thank you. That documentation really helps

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are using [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) and from [documentation](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#git-status-summary-information), it means:

1. `master` -  current branch
2. `+2` - 2 files added
3. `~0` - Zero files modified
4. `-0` - Zero files Removed
5. `!` - There are untracked changes in the working tree